# Why is this true?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Theorem 2.13: $m$ vectors in $R^n$ are linearly dependent if $n < m.$**

My professor gave us this theorem, but didn't have time for a proof. I don't see why its true.

Lets say you have a set of vectors:

$$S = \{u_1, u_2, u_3, ... u_m\}$$ in $R^{n}$. Say the set is linearly independent and that $n = m + 1$.

Now add the vectors $u_{m+1} =  2u_1$ and $u_{m+2} =  2u_2%$ into the set.
 Now the set consists of:

$$S = \{u_1, u_2, u_3 ... u_{m+2}\}$$

Now the number of vectors are still independent, but the number of vectors, $m+2 > n$. Doesn't this violate the theorem?

Comment: Your set isn't linearly independent anymore. You have (for example) the linear relations $2u_1 - u_{m+1} = 0$ and $24 u_2 - 10 u_{m+2} = 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it, thanks. Post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a multiple of an $u_i$ to the set $S = \{u_1,\dotsc,u_m\}$, then the resulting set is no longer linearly independent. Here, adding $2u_1$ introduces the linear relation $2u_1 - u_{m+1} = 0$.